# jqgrid - how do i persist advanced multiple search on reload of grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid that reloads itself on a set interval and is using the multiple search option.  All is working great, except when the reload happens I am losing any filtering/searching that was previously entered and all data shows.

How can I persist any filtering/searching after the reload.   Code is below.   Any advice is appreciated:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            datatype: 'json',
            url: 'GetWorkItems.ashx?view=MyActiveItems',
            height: "100%",
            scrollOffset: 0,
            jsonReader: {
                root: "rows",
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",
                repeatitems: false,
                cell: "cell",
                id: "Id",
                userdata: "userdata",
                subgrid: {
                    root: "rows",
                    repeatitems: true,
                    cell: "cell"
                }
            },
            colNames: ['', 'ID', 'TopParentID', 'Title', 'Assigned To', 'Status', 'Priority', 'Classification', 'Affected User', 'Support Group', 'Last Modified'],
            colModel: [
                  { name: 'Icon', index: 'Icon', align: 'right', width: 18, sortable: false, formatter: iconFormatter, search: false },
                  { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 45, sorttype: 'int', firstsortorder: 'desc' },
                  { name: 'TopParentId', index: 'TopParentId', width: 65, align: 'center', sorttype: 'int', hidden: true },
                  { name: 'Title', index: 'Title', width: 180 },
                  { name: 'AssignedUser', index: 'AssignedUser', width: 100, align: 'center' },
                  { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', width: 60, align: 'center' },
                  { name: 'Priority', index: 'Priority', width: 50, align: 'center' },
                  { name: 'Category', index: 'Category', width: 120, align: 'center' },
                  { name: 'AffectedUser', index: 'AffectedUser', width: 100, align: 'center' },
                  { name: 'Tier', index: 'Tier', width: 100, align: 'center' },
                  { name: 'LastModified', index: 'LastModified', width: 120, align: 'center', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s0', newformat: 'm/d/Y h:i A' }
                  }],
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum: 15,
            width: 980,
            sortname: 'Id',
            sortorder: 'asc',
            viewrecords: true,
            autowidth: true,
            gridview: true,
            loadonce: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            caption: 'All Active Work Items Assigned To Me',
            onSelectRow: function (id) {
                //doing a redirect here
            }
        });

        $.extend($.jgrid.search, { multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true, recreateFilter: true, overlay: 0 });
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { add: false, edit: false, del: false });

        function iconFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            return '<img src="./images/' + cellvalue + '" alt="workitem" />';
        };

        var interval = parseInt($("#<%=hidRefreshInterval.ClientID %>").val());
        window.setTimeout(refreshGrid, interval);

        function refreshGrid() {
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
            window.setTimeout(refreshGrid, interval);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hum, I just tested on my own project and setting multiple search parameters and then triggering a reload kept all of those setting, the grid by default posted back to the controller all the search parameters.  Why are you needing multipleSearch? Why are you needing to reset your datatype on refresh?

Comment: I don't think the `multipleSearch: true` is necessary either.  You should be able to have multiple filters without this (I don't personally set it).  You might also want to get rid of the jsonReader as I also don't think it is necessary.  There should be a ton of clean examples around for you to build up from.  In the end did this put you on the right path?

Comment: Yes I got it working by removing the reset of datatype, and changing the JSON Reader like so:   page: function () { return 1; },
                    total: function () { return 1; },
                    records: function (obj) {
                        if ($.isArray(obj)) {
                            return obj.length;
                        }
                        if ($.isArray(obj.items)) {
                            return obj.items.length;
                        }
                        return 0;
                    },

Comment: Heh, well I'm not sure if there is anything substantive to put as an answer below... put in the reset of the datatype?

Comment: That will work :)  Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we figured out the `'setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' })` was not needed so should be removed.